# Android - CSS vertical centering doesn't work

Tags: android, css, alignment, center

The following container should be vertically centered...:

```
<div style="
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  z-index:555;
"></div>
```

...and it is in all major browsers except Android. Is there any way to vertically center this in Android as well? It displays in top left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
top: 50%; margin-top: -25px;
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I figured it out as well. Thanks! But is there any reason why Android fails to work with my initial solution?

Comment: Not sure tbh... It will also depend on your version of Android!

Comment: I use 4.2.2 and it's driving me mad for a few days :) iOS is a lot less popular but it works a lot better for me (at least since iOS 5 and iOS 6). Too bad that Android has 75%+ of market because I hate its browser at this moment.